# Defining webpack externals for font-awesome module

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

I'm working on a small framework using jQuery, Bootstrap and FontAwesome.

All are installed using Yarn without problem!

In some configurations, I need to produce a bundle of my framework not including these librairies which be loaded locally or from a CDN; so I'm using Webpack "externals" setting, which is OK for JQuery and Bootstrap, but I can't make it working for FontAwesome which is always included into my bundle!

My configuration is as follows:

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jquery',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
    fontawesome: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free'
}
```

FontAwesome is included from my main script like this:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
```

I have tested several syntaxes for "externals" setting, without success until now!

Any idea?

Best regards,

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

`fontawesome` would be the dependency of some other library.